# ABMSoundCloudAPI: Convert Objective-C block to Swift closure

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, soundcloud, swift2

I'm using the ABMSoundCloudAPI from (https://github.com/andresbrun/ABMSoundCloudAPI).

I'm trying to convert the Objective-C block to Swift block. I'm using Xcode 7.

Objective-C

```
- (void)requestSongById:(NSString *)songID
            withSuccess:(void (^)(NSDictionary *songDict))successBlock
                failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failureBlock;
```

I tried the following in Swift:

```
SoundCloudPort.requestSongById(songID, withSuccess: {(songDict) -> Void in successBlock()}, failure: {(error) -> Void in failure()})
```

It gives me a error stating "Extra argument 'withSuccess' in call.

If someone can help I appreciate it.

Comment: Have been looking for this API. Great stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func soundcloudTrackIDConvert(trackID: String) -> String{
    let partOne = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/"
    let partTwo = "/stream?client_id="
    let clientID = "0000"
    let trackID = "0000"
    let completeURL = partOne + trackID + partTwo + clientID
    print("completeURL: \(completeURL)")
    return completeURL
}
```